# Calculate Value of form fields & update Total

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where i need to auto calculate value for checked row.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOBaNN?editors=1010

I am calculating the value for the text field on `keyup` function but need to do following

1. Keep All text fields disabled
2. Second i need to enable only text field related to the checkbox checked
3. Third Calculate sum for only Checked text field

Right now i am able to calculate value for all checkbox not sure how to map checked checbox to related input and calculate values accordingly.

tried few thing but it keep breaking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Too disable your text fields set the disabled property to true.

```
$(".auto-sum").each(function () {
     $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

2) Enable inputs with checkboxes

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var active = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('.auto-sum[name=Amount' + id + ']').attr('disabled', !active);
    calculateSum();
});
```

3) Skip disabled inputs when calculating

```
$(".auto-sum").each(function () {
     if ($(this).prop('disabled')) return;
     [...]
});
```

I updated your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmJgxM?editors=1011

Comment: I question regarding this solution. How can i reset the disabled textbox value to 0

Comment: I modified this code to make it work ` if ($(this).prop('disabled'))
                {
                    this.value = 0;
                    return
                };`